# Cast error when DataTable.Load from DataReader

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a simple function that returns a Datatable based on a simple select statement.  `Under some circumstances`, it generates a message about "Specified cast is not valid" with dt.Load(rdr);.  I've tried looking at the results of the select statement in other SQL tools and I don't see anything wrong with the data.  If I were trying to force a char into an Int column or something similar this would make since (which is what I see in the SO postings), but I haven't specified any datatypes yet.

Is this an issue with the first record initiating a different datatype than subsequent rows or is it something else?  I'm stumped.

```
  public DataTable getData(OracleCommand oraCmd)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(OracleConnectStr))
        {
            conn.Open();
            oraCmd.Connection = conn;
            using (oraCmd)
            {
                try
                {
                    using (OracleDataReader rdr = oraCmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        dt.Load(rdr);
                        conn.Dispose();
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception(string.Format("Error occurred.  The error was {0}.", e.Message));
                }
            }
        }
```

Stack Trace:

```
[Exception: Error occurred.  The error was Specified cast is not valid..]
   ***.DatabaseUtils.getData(OracleCommand oraCmd)
in d:\***\DatabaseUtils.cs:149
           ***.Transcripts.BindData(String orderByClause) 
in ***\Transcripts.aspx.cs:365
          ***.Transcripts.search_click(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
in ***\Transcripts.aspx.cs:81
           System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628722
           System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
           System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
           System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
           System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
           System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is the full exception? message, stacktrace, etc

Comment: Okay.  I think I've found the problem.  The error is not happening when I try to load the data, but is actually happening deeper in the stack in `Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleDataReader.GetDecimal(Int32 i)`.  Thank you Kritner for helping me to dig a little deeper!  Once I figured this out, I was able to modify the SQL statement to avoid the error.

Comment: @Trebor what was the actual problem and how did you solved it?